# Modify data in outgoing UDP packets on linux

Tags: python, linux, sockets, iptables

The RADIUS part of it is not important to the query, but thought I would explain the context:

I have a linux based radius server that always includes a certain attribute in the "Access-Accept" packet, that one of my network devices does not like. The server does not have an option to disable said attribute. I was looking into the possibility of using a script to modify the outgoing access accept to remove the attribute and recalculate the checksum and Radius authenticator fields.

I will be able to code a python script which creates a UDP socket to listen on and then modify the radius packet as required. The part I am stuck with is:
(A) How to redirect outgoing traffic to my script's socket?
(B) How to ensure source and destination IP/port remain the same?

Doing some research for (A), [it looks like](https://serverfault.com/questions/318960/easy-way-to-edit-the-traffic-coming-from-a-tcp-host-linux) we can use iptables to redirect incoming data to a script:

> The suggested command in the above link:
>   iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -s yourhost -d desthost -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to 10101

However, I need to modify the outgoing data.
I am guessing I need to modify PREROUTING to POSTROUTING
There also seems to be a NAT keyword. I am unsure how that will affect the IP addresses.

I am also concerned, if my script does send out the modified packet with the same IPs/Ports, will it not hit the iptable rule once again, and get stuck in an infinite loop? How do I avoid this?

For query (B), I suppose using Scapy is an option to ensure IP/port remains the same in the modified packet. If there is an easier option, I would like to know that.

Any help with the above would be truly appreciated.

Comment: It's probably a lot easier to just edit the source code and rebuild your RADIUS server.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the NFQUEUE iptables functionality: if a packet matches your rule, it will be redirected in userspace to a specific queue.

For instance, to intercept all radius packet to your "non-standard" network device:

`iptables -A OUTPUT -d <device> -p udp --sport <radius_port> -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1`

Then you have to run a script that binds to the Nfqueue and modifies the packets accordingly.

A small python sample with nfqueue and scapy (you'll need to install the dependancies):

```
from scapy.all import *
from netfilterqueue import NetfilterQueue
queueId = 1

def doStuff(packet):
    [do your packet mangling here]

    packet.set_payload(str(modified_packet_payload))
    packet.accept()

# bind the callback function to the queue
nfqueue = NetfilterQueue()
nfqueue.bind(queueId, doStuff)

try:
    nfqueue.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you @Simone. This addresses most of it. However, will the packet sent with scapy be checked against the iptables once more (resulting in it going back into the script in an infinite loop?)?

Comment: The packet will exit the OUTPUT chain, enter the NFQUEUE then it will be re-injected after the OUTPUT chain, so no loop. Of course, any matching packet will be injected **once** in the nfqueue, you need to define in the code which packets need mangling and which packet doesn't.